# R - Passing column name through ellipsis in R

Tags: r, ellipsis

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = data.frame(id = 1:10, wt = 71:80, gender = rep(1:2, 5), race = rep(1:2, 5))
```

I'm trying to write a function that takes on a dataframe as a first argument together with any number of arguments that represent column names in that dataframe and use these column names to perform operations on the dataframe. My function would look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
myFunction <- function(df, ...){
 columns <- list(...)
  for (i in 1:length(columns)){
   var <- enquo(columns[[i]])
   df <- df %>% group_by(!!var)
  }
 df2 = summarise(df, mean = mean(wt))
 return(df2)
}
```

I call the function as the following

```
myFunction(df, race, gender)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in myFunction(df, race, gender) : object 'race' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert the elements in `...` to quosures and then do the evaluation (`!!!`)

```
myFunction <- function(dat, ...){
    columns <- quos(...) # convert to quosures

 dat %>% 
     group_by(!!! columns) %>% # evaluate 
     summarise(mean = mean(wt))

 }

myFunction(df, race, gender)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   race [?]
#   race gender  mean
#  <int>  <int> <dbl>
#1     1      1    75
#2     2      2    76

myFunction(df, race)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   race  mean
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1    75
#2     2    76
```

NOTE: In the OP's example, 'race' and 'gender' are the same

If it change it, will see the difference

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, wt = 71:80, gender = rep(1:2, 5), 
      race = rep(1:2, each = 5))

myFunction(df, race, gender)
myFunction(df, race)
myFunction(df, gender)
```

---

If we decide to pass the arguments as quoted strings, then we can make use of `group_by_at`

```
myFunction2 <- function(df, ...) {
 columns <- c(...)
 df %>% 
   group_by_at(columns) %>%
   summarise(mean= mean(wt))

 }

myFunction2(df, "race", "gender")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was quite helpful.

Comment: @AbdallahAtef  The `!!` is used when we have a single element to evaluate, `!!!` for more than 1 element.  It also works with 1 element though